# Would it be possible that we have one Google Cloud function listen to multiple topics?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

[image]

So we can set up the Cloud Function to listen to one topic, like the graph showed here.

Would it be possible that we have one function listen to multiple topics?

For example, I could have a function email me the errors. And if I can have this function to listen to multiple topics (each topic will be reporting one particular process error), I don't have to have one function for each one topic which doing the same thing, email me the error message.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your objection to having multiple functions?

Comment: What I mean is right now One Cloud function can listen to one topic. Could we set up one cloud function to listen to multiple topics? 

Such as topic 1:  bigquery transfer failure. topic 2: google cloud storage upload failure topic 3:  elasticsearch load failure

I don't want 3 functions for these 3 topics. I just want one function to listen to all these 3 topics.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid having one function for each topic.  Are you just concerned about duplication of code?

Comment: Doug, yes. I want to avoid duplicated codes and duplicated functions.

I don't understand why one function only have one trigger.

in pub/sub architecture, could sub subscribe from multiple topics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a separate trigger for each PubSub topic, but can easily then call a simple higher-order function to do all the work.

```
exports.helloPubSub = functions.pubsub.topic('topic-name').onPublish((message) => {
  pubsubHandler('topic-name', message)
});

exports.worldPubSub = functions.pubsub.topic('topic-name2').onPublish((message) => {
  pubsubHandler('topic-name2', message)
});

function pubsubHandler(topic, message) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Frank, not sure I understand you here.

So like Doug said, I cannot avoid having one function for each topic. 

So do you mean 

1) All the works will be in this high order function.
2) Then I still need to create one function for one topic. But each topic's function would simply call the high order function to do the work?

Comment: @searain You have to declare a Cloud Function for each topic, but the implementation for each function can be delegated to a single function.  Frank is using the Firebase SDK for this - you will probably want to do the same using the standard Cloud Functions syntax.